# Android localization any region doesn't work for some languages and uses English instead

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-locale

I though adding just `zh` folder with translations will be used for all regions but it seems if the device language is set to Mandarin Chinese (zh-rTW) then it will use English. I have to create `zh-rTW` folder as well and add the translations there as well.

So I don't understand Android "Any Region" logic or there are some exceptions with Chinese languages only? Are there any exceptions with any other languages? Is there any documentation about this then?

[image]